# What is the alternative for <center> in Angular?

Tags: angular

```
Error: Template parse errors:
'center' is not a known element:
1. If 'center' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
  [ERROR ->]<center><h2>my-candid works!</h2>
  <div [style.color]="isSpecial ? 'red' : 'green'">This is style bi"): ng:///AppModule/MyCandidComponent.html@1:2
```

Comment: `<center>` isn’t supported in HTML5; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Answer (score 2):

Are you just trying to center text?

```
<h2 [ngStyle]="{'text-align': 'center'}">my-candid works!</h2>
```

Or do center a div you can always use CSS, for example:

```
.yourDiv {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```